# Trigonometry Addition Thereom

Tags: trigonometry

Using the expansion of

a. $\sin(+)$, prove that $\sin75°=\sqrt 6+\sqrt{24}$

b. $\sin(+)$, prove that $\tan75°=2+\sqrt 3$

Where to start? draw up triangle of sin 75? find other values? help please.

Comment: part a is simple.For part b firstly find out $\sin 75^\circ $ and $\cos 75^\circ $.you have $\sin 75^\circ$ for $\cos 75^\circ$ use $\cos (A+B)=\cos A\cdot \cos B-\sin A\cdot \sin B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, you start by listing all angles of which you know exact values for $\sin$ and $\cos$ (should include $0°$, $30°$, $45°$, $60°$, $90°$ at least), then see how you can express $75°$.

Comment: Oh thank you just solved it !

Answer (score 1):

Hint

- $\sin(75^\circ) = \sin(45^\circ+30^\circ) = \sin(45^\circ) \cdot \cos(30^\circ) + \cos(30^\circ) \cdot \sin(45^\circ)$.
- $\displaystyle \tan(75^\circ) = \frac{\sin(75^\circ)}{\cos(75^\circ)} = \frac{\sin(45^\circ+30^\circ)}{\cos(45^\circ+30^\circ)}$